# Firebase Messaging error while installing pod file

Tags: swift, terminal, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was trying to install Firebase's pod for messaging and I got this error in terminal....
"Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Messaging` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target."

This is what I have in my podfile

```
"# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, ‘8.0’
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
# use_frameworks!

target 'PZPlayer' do

pod ‘Firebase’
pod ‘Firebase/Messaging’
end
"
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '9.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift 
 use_frameworks!

target 'PZPlayer' do

pod ‘Firebase’
pod ‘Firebase/Messaging’
end
```

This should be your podfile. Try it.

Comment: Anytime! :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I did more or less than the guy told us 
but my steps were a little different:

1) on the Terminal: 
    go to your project folder: 
  1.1) cd Desktop/YourApp
   1.2) YOURMAC:YourApp Fernanda$ sudo pod init

2) change your file Podfile to:

` # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'YourApp' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

# Pods for YourApp
pod 'Firebase'

end 
 `

3) on the Terminal:  pod install

4) Now, change your file Podfile again to: 
`# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'YourApp' do 
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks 
  use_frameworks!

# Pods for YourApp 
pod 'Firebase' 
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end 
`

5)  on the Terminal:  pod update
 
Sorry my about my English, 
Good Look!